How to extract the parent JSON property name using JSONPath?
I would like to extract the content_filter_results property names that have been filtered, e.g., foo here:
{
  "choices": [
    {
      "content_filter_results": {
        "foo": {
          "filtered": true,
          "severity": "safe"
        },
        "bar": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        },
        "baz": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

This JSONPath expression $.choices[*].content_filter_results[?(@.filtered==true)] selects its children properties, e.g.,
[
  {
    "filtered": true,
    "severity": "safe"
  }
]

but I would like to be able to get foo.

Try using $.choices[*].content_filter_results[?(@.filtered==true)].keys()

Is this valid? It does not work in https://jsonpath.com nor in Python using jsonpath-ng.

Can we use third-party package in this context? I suggest using jsonpath-ng.ext. Provided an answer related the same, please check.

Yes, I’m using it already.
